# CJKTokenizerFactory issue in Solr 5.x

Tags: solr

I am facing issue with CJKTokenizerFactory in solr 5.x. When I use  it throws error. Is this tokenizer has been removed from solr 5.x and Can I use below configuration for the same.

Thanks
Shruti

Comment: whats the error it throws?

Comment: can you provide more info like fieldType definition and error?

Comment: Error:-- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core log: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "cjktext": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/tokenizer: Error loading class 'solr.CJKTokenizerFactory'   fieldType:- <fieldType name="cjktext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="250">
        <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
             
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its been depricated. Check here.

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKTokenizerFactory.html

You can use CJKBigramFilterFactory instead of CJKTokenizerFactory.